# How do I display a div right next to another div?

Tags: css

I am currently developing my own website. The first div container integrates a image to html. The second div with the classname "face" should show up directly beneath the image. It contains a text with predefined width and height.

Now the problem: It does not show up on the right of the image div. How can I show it on the right side?

```css
.face {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 21, 166), #115FD8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.start {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.postpreview {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}
.one-half {
  float: left;
  width: 48.717948717948715%;
  margin-left: 2.564102564102564%;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-half start postpreview">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://vocaloid.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/KAITO-6th-anniversary-2015-Project-DIVA-Arcade-Diamond-Dust-750x256.jpg" class="attachment-Beitragsbild wp-post-image">
  </a>
</div>



<div class="face"><a href="http://vocaloid.de/out/vbrasil" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your 1st paragraph says to appear below; but the second says to the right. Which?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/13m3vbu1/1/

Comment: @Donte'Trumble Yes thanks! But what did you change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. http://jsfiddle.net/13m3vbu1/3/

Insert into your css:

```
.face {
    text-align: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 21, 166), #115FD8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.one-half {
    float: left;
    width: 48.717948717948715%;
    margin-left: 2.564102564102564%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.one-half > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I removed the redundant CSS that isn't needed as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the div with a class face to show on the right side of div one-half use float: left and instead of using pixels in .face use percent it's more flexible

**CSS**

```
.one-half {
     float:left;
     width: 45%; //adjust in what % you want
     display: inline;
}
.face {
     float: left;
     width: 45%; //adjust in what % you want
     display: inline;
}
```